# Modify middleware response

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

My requirement: write a middleware that filters all "bad words" out of a response that comes from another subsequent middleware (e.g. Mvc).

The problem: streaming of the response. So when we come back to our `FilterBadWordsMiddleware` from a subsequent middleware, which already wrote to the response, we are too late to the party... because response started already sending, which yields to the wellknown error `response has already started`...

So since this is a requirement in many various situations -- how to deal with it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**.NET Core 3+ solution with proper resource handling:**

Replace response stream by `MemoryStream` to prevent its sending. Return the original stream after the response is modified:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var response = context.Response;

    //uncomment this line to re-read context.Request.Body stream
    //context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    
    var originBody = response.Body;
    using var newBody = new MemoryStream();
    response.Body = newBody;

    await _next(context);

    await ModifyResponseAsync(response);
    
    newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await newBody.CopyToAsync(originBody);
    response.Body = originBody;
}

private async Task ModifyResponseAsync(HttpResponse response)
{
    var stream = response.Body;
    
    //uncomment to re-read the response stream
    //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, leaveOpen: true);
    string originalResponse = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    
    //add modification logic

    string modifiedResponse = "Hello from Stackoverflow";
    stream.SetLength(0);
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, leaveOpen: true);
    await writer.WriteAsync(modifiedResponse);
    await writer.FlushAsync();
    response.ContentLength = stream.Length;
}
```

**Original .NET Core 1 answer**

Replace response stream by `MemoryStream` to prevent its sending. Return the original stream after the response is modified:

```cs
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        bool modifyResponse = true;
        Stream originBody = null;

        if (modifyResponse)
        {
            //uncomment this line only if you need to read context.Request.Body stream
            //context.Request.EnableRewind();

            originBody = ReplaceBody(context.Response);
        }

        await _next(context);

        if (modifyResponse)
        {
            //as we replaced the Response.Body with a MemoryStream instance before,
            //here we can read/write Response.Body
            //containing the data written by middlewares down the pipeline 

            //finally, write modified data to originBody and set it back as Response.Body value
            ReturnBody(context.Response, originBody);
        }
    }

    private Stream ReplaceBody(HttpResponse response)
    {
        var originBody = response.Body;
        response.Body = new MemoryStream();
        return originBody;
    }

    private void ReturnBody(HttpResponse response, Stream originBody)
    {
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        response.Body.CopyTo(originBody);
        response.Body = originBody;
    }
```

It's a workaround and it can cause performance problems. I hope to see a better solution here.

Comment: This works, thanks! I found that in some cases attaching a callback to `context.Response.OnStarting()` works as well, but not when modifying responses. Also I don't like using `OnStarting()`, because it breaks the iterative middleware workflow.

Comment: For future reference, before writing to Response, it helps to set the Content Length property.

Comment: In Dotnet Core 3, I am getting "System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch" to solve this I added context.Response.ContentLength = json.Length;

Comment: Thanks you all for noticing! I've added a relevant solution to the answer. Works fine on .NET 7.

Comment: Why the `originalResponse` is always an empty string? How can I **modify**, not the replace response body?

Comment: I found solution: `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` should be added before `using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, leaveOpen: true);`.

Comment: @EgoPingvina this means the stream has already been read before getting to rewriting middleware, which does't happen by default. I've updated the answer with optional `Seek` call. Thanks for the comment, and sorry for the extremely late reply.

Comment: I also found it strange, but it didn't work without this line. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 17):

A simpler version based on the code I used:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The middleware Invoke method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="httpContext">The current <see cref="HttpContext"/>.</param>
/// <returns>A Task to support async calls.</returns>
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var originBody = httpContext.Response.Body;
    try
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        httpContext.Response.Body = memStream;

        await _next(httpContext).ConfigureAwait(false);

        memStream.Position = 0;
        var responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

        //Custom logic to modify response
        responseBody = responseBody.Replace("hello", "hi", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        var memoryStreamModified = new MemoryStream();
        var sw = new StreamWriter(memoryStreamModified);
        sw.Write(responseBody);
        sw.Flush();
        memoryStreamModified.Position = 0;

        await memoryStreamModified.CopyToAsync(originBody).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        httpContext.Response.Body = originBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do get a `System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written.`

Comment: @JonneKleijer use context.Response.ContentLength = responseBody.Length; after  memoryStreamModified.Position = 0; like Oriel Dayanim suggested in the comment

Comment: Why are you using ".ConfigureAwait(false)"?  The code seems to work with out it?

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to comment since my score is too low.
So just wanted to post my extension of the excellent top solution, and a modification for .NET Core 3.0+

First of all

```cs
context.Request.EnableRewind();
```

has been changed to

```cs
context.Request.EnableBuffering();
```

in .NET Core 3.0+

And here's how I read/write the body content:

First a filter, so we just modify the content types we're interested in

```cs
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> validContentTypes = new HashSet<string>() { "text/html", "application/json", "application/javascript" };
```

It's a solution for transforming nuggeted texts like [[[Translate me]]] into its translation. This way I can just mark up everything that needs to be translated, read the po-file we've gotten from the translator, and then do the translation replacement in the output stream - regardless if the nuggeted texts is in a razor view, javascript or ... whatever.
Kind of like the TurquoiseOwl i18n package does, but in .NET Core, which that excellent package unfortunately doesn't support.

```cs
...

if (modifyResponse)
{
    //as we replaced the Response.Body with a MemoryStream instance before,
    //here we can read/write Response.Body
    //containing the data written by middlewares down the pipeline

    var contentType = context.Response.ContentType?.ToLower();
    contentType = contentType?.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();   // Filter out text/html from "text/html; charset=utf-8"

    if (validContentTypes.Contains(contentType))
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body))
        {
            // Read the body
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var responseBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

            // Replace [[[Bananas]]] with translated texts - or Bananas if a translation is missing
            responseBody = NuggetReplacer.ReplaceNuggets(poCatalog, responseBody);

            // Create a new stream with the modified body, and reset the content length to match the new stream
            var requestContent = new StringContent(responseBody, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
            context.Response.Body = await requestContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();//modified stream
            context.Response.ContentLength = context.Response.Body.Length;
        }
    }

    //finally, write modified data to originBody and set it back as Response.Body value
    await ReturnBody(context.Response, originBody);
}
...

private Task ReturnBody(HttpResponse response, Stream originBody)
{
    response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await response.Body.CopyToAsync(originBody);
    response.Body = originBody;
}
```

Comment: What does ReturnBody do?

Comment: Sorry, added the RetunBody-function to the solution suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A "real" production scenario may be found here: [tethys logging middeware](https://github.com/saturn72/tethys/blob/851ac6d6235c5e2d2f62c3d4343b8e862062a3c2/src/Tethys.Server/Middlewares/RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware.cs#L47)

If you follow the logic presented in the link, do not forget to add`httpContext.Request.EnableRewind()` prior calling `_next(httpContext)` (extension method of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal` namespace).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC you can try [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters). They seem to allow changing the response.