# AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2 return error if response body length exceeds threshold

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an AspNet.Core.Mvc REST API that is routed through a proxy gateway. The gateway has a limit of 10mb for the response body. If the body is over that threshold it returns 500 Internal Server Error.

**My goal:**
To check the size of the response body before returning from my API project and if it is over that threshold, return a BadRequest error instead, with a helpful error message in the response body content. Something like, "The response is too large. Try narrowing your request."

I've tried handling this in middleware, where the byte size of the body is known, but this is too late and the framework prevents this. I've tried working around this, something like this where you swap out the Body temporarily with a MemoryStream:

[Modify middleware response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508028/modify-middleware-response)

However, the status code is already set to 200 at that point and the framework throws an error if you try to change it. Here is the code snippet from the middleware where it copies the new response stream to the original body:

```
// Replace the body with a BadRequest error notifying user that the response
// was too large and they should narrow down their search parameters.
var errorStream = new MemoryStream();
var sw = new StreamWriter(errorStream);
sw.Write("Response exceeds maximum size. Try narrowing request parameters or setting a smaller page size if applicable.");
sw.Flush();
errorStream.Position = 0;

await errorStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; // throws exception!
```

I've also tried to handle it in the Controller method itself before returning, by serializing the response content to json, then converting the json string to bytes to check the size:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, jsonSerializerSettings);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
```

But that is all work that the framework will do for me, and seems wasteful (and frankly ugly). Is there a way to set this as the response and return it from the Controller? Maybe I can create a base class for the Controller that all API methods can use that will do this logic?

This all seems like a lot of trouble for something seemingly simple. I'm hoping someone here has a better solution.

Comment: First, .NET Core 2.2 went out of support a long time ago. Even .NET Core 3.1, the Long Term Support version that replaces it reaches End of Life this December. The current LTS version is .NET 6.

Comment: Second, why is the response so big? What are you returning? What is `value`? It's far better to check the size of the returned data *before* serialization. If you return rows from a query, you can use a `TOP` in SQL or `Take` in LINQ to limit the results from the start.

Comment: I agree that it is far easier to limit the number of records in the response before serializing, however it doesn't allow for any precision at all in terms of bytes.

Comment: My question is specifically how to check the byte size of the response body before sending it.

Comment: By that point you've already paid the cost of retrieving and serializing data that won't be sent to the caller. I'd argue that byte precision doesn't matter and you should be able to reject such requests as soon as possible

Comment: I think you make a fair point. I may just fall back to setting a reasonable limit on the number of records that are returned so that it should be well below the 10mb restriction. There is a lot of variation in the size of each record, but I think it should be fine if it is a lower limit than what could theoretically fit. Thank you for your input.