# How to replace odata links in reverse proxy using asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

In a asp.net core reverse proxy setup, the goal is to intercept the OData response from the target server. You then replace all instances of the target server's URL with the proxy server's URL before forwarding it to the client. The received response has a content type of "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal". The objective is to achieve this transformation while keeping the response intact and without altering the response type.

I have implemented reverse proxy similar way given in the link.

- https://www.google.com/amp/s/auth0.com/blog/amp/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/

Comment: you have this invoke method in your custom middleware, https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC8jO.png then what you need to do is getting the response content, then modify the data and update the content. What's your trouble here? Can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508028/modify-middleware-response) help you?

Comment: I am able to modify the content , but could not set content type explicitely as "odata.metadata=minimal" while returning the response. Due to which client side not able to generate the next link.

Comment: sorry I'm not able to understand your issue well... Did you get any error/exception?

Comment: works fine with content-type application/json, after response modification, forgot to update content-type and content-length header.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the received response from the target server, applied below changes worked for me:

```
if ( IsContentOfType(responseMessage, "application/json") )
{
    var stringContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);
   // modify content
   context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
   context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");
   context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8;");
   await context.Response.WriteAsync(stringContent, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```